# Is it possible to copy data, formatting, ranges and formulas from a given selection to a new sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

The sheet I am using has become unstable and the workarounds on the web just don't work. So I figured I would try and copy everything across to a new sheet.

Comment: What workarounds? This is an incredibly broad question. What's unstable? Why do you want to do this? etc

Comment: There is a known problem whereby sheets suddenly balloon in size due to formatting. The fixes recommended by MS e.g. select everything and 'clear all' do not work neither does XSFormatCleaner.xla   The sheet I am working with contains a lot of ranges and formulas and so on, so the solution at this point would be to copy it to a clean sheet

Comment: So in copying you want to capture formatting and named ranges?

Comment: "I figured I would try and copy everything across to a new sheet" Sounds like a plan, what happened when you tried?

Comment: There are about 500+ ranges, formulas etc I would have thought that there was a way of automating the copying of this in addition to formatting and formulas

Answer (score 0):

Like you say, it's the formulas that are making the file so big.  If you need to copy all the formulas, you're going to struggle to reduce the file size.  If there are some formulas that you can do without, this will help.  I find that removing Vlookup formulas makes a big difference.
If you have vlookup and are able to do without them, copy -> paste special (values) all the cells with Vlookup formulas in first.  Then copy -> paste the rest of the data into a new file..

Comment: No it's not the formulas that are making the file big. This is a known issue whereby certain formatting causes the sheet to expand enormously https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244435  none of these workarounds work for me